# Spring Boot - Null fields of class during testi with TestRestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, testing, null

I created some REST-api and checked the performance with Postman - everything works correctly.But when I'm trying to test the same endpoint using a TestRestTemplate all fields except 'name' arrived to the controller as null. What's the problem?

There are two classes in my app: ClassA and ClassB "one-to-many" related. But it's so strange when "id" field is null in ClassA. And "List" field is null too.

Section class

```
@Entity
public class Section implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "section_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Expose
    private String name;
    
    @Expose
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "section", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<GeologicalClass> geologicalClasses;
    
    // Default constructor 'cause JPA
    protected Section() {}
    // Own constructor
    public Section(String secName) {
        this.name = secName;
        this.geologicalClasses = new ArrayList<GeologicalClass>();
    }
    ...
}
```

GeologicalClass class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="geoclasses")
public class GeologicalClass implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Expose
    private String name;

    @Expose
    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "section_id")
    protected Section section;

    // Default constructor 'cause JPA
    protected GeologicalClass() {}
    // Own constructor
    public GeologicalClass(Section secName, String geoName, String geoCode) {
        this.section = secName;
        this.name = geoName;
        this.code = geoCode;
    }
    ...
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class SectionController {

    @Autowired
    private SectionService sectionService;

    // Find all records in DB
    @GetMapping("/sections")
    public String findAll() {
       return sectionService.findAllToJSON();
    }

    // Find one section by ID and return info
    @GetMapping("/sections/{id}")
    public String findById(@PathVariable Integer id) 
            throws JsonProcessingException {
        return sectionService.findOneToJSON(id);
    }
    ...
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class SectionService {

    @Autowired
    private SectionRepository sectionRepository;

    // Find one section by id and return info in correct form without id;
    // simple method shows ArrayList as mem's address
    public String findOneToJSON(Integer id) {
        Section section = sectionRepository.findOne(id);
        if (section == null) 
            throw new NotFoundException("! Section with this ID is not found !");
        // With only fields with @Expose
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create(); 
        return gson.toJson(section);
    }
    
    // Find each section and show it with general {}
    // (uses previous function findOneToJSON)
    public String findAllToJSON() {
        Iterable<Section> sections = sectionRepository.findAll();
        if (sections.toString().equals("[]")) {
            throw new NotFoundException("! No any section found (DB is empty) !");
        }
        String output = "";
        for (Section sec : sections) {
            output += findOneToJSON(sec.getId());
        }
        return output;
    }
    ...
}
```

SectionControllerTest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SectionController.class, Application.class})
public class SectionControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SectionRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setDb() {
        Section section = new Section("Section1");
        GeologicalClass geo = new GeologicalClass(section, "GeoClass11", "GC11");
        section.addGeoClass(geo);
        repository.save(section);
    }

    @After
    public void resetDb() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void whenGetSections() {                
        ResponseEntity<Section> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/sections", Section.class);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
        assertThat(response.getBody().getName(), is("Section1"));
        assertThat(response.getBody().getId(), is(1));
    }
}
```

RESULTS of test
without `assertThat(response.getBody().getId(), is(1));` test passed. But if I try get any field other than name, test is failed:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <1>
     but: was null
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
    at testing.dao.SectionControllerTest.whenCreateSection(SectionControllerTest.java:52)
```

And `List<GeologicalClass> geologicalclasses` is null. Also if I creae test to "/sections/1" GET request, test is faild, 'cause used id in `findOne` function, I think. But "/sections" GET request is passed, 'couse.. why?

Comment: I'm not used to restemplate, but I'd expect to request an array or list of entities for that endpoint in restTemplate.getForEntity. Other than that I wouldn't comvert to json on the service, I don't think it makes sense at all. You usually want to convert to json in the controller or even better, let jackson or some other library take care of that out of your logic. But you want your service to return entities, so you can interact with them in a java native way.

Comment: @Eduardo Pérez, this is required format for getForEntity, so I can't return it to Section or List<Section>.. Moreover, I created some other tests (POST req, DEL req, special GET (not CRUD)) and all of is passed, if I don't use ID field. 
What about json - thanks for you advice. I'm just starting to learn spring and RESTs, and this approach seemed to me the most correct

Comment: I have taken a better look at your case and I have some observations:
1- I already mentioned it before, but you don't have to convert the entities to JSON yourself, you can let a library, such as jackson do that for you. In this case, spring-boot should take care of everything, so if your restcontroller returns a Section, springboot will set up everything so that it get converted to json: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-write-a-json-rest-service

Comment: 2.- In your custom conversion I think you are committing an error when getting the collection, because you are not wrapping the collection using [].
Also, getting all the elements and then querying each of them is quite awkward, because you are doing N + 1 queries to the database instead of doing just 1

Comment: 3.- What I meant in the first comment is that I think you should use this:
ResponseEntity<Section> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/sections", Section[].class);, however, until you fix the previous point, I think that's not going to work, because if you don't wrap your JSON with [], it's not going to be detected as a collection